# What could make a person get ill from not eating often enough?

Tags: food, nutrition, diet

Say a person needs to eat every 3 hours, or s\he gets physically ill with fatigue and cold sweating, and this is the case every day.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a symptom of [hypogylcemia.](http://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-topics/Diabetes/hypoglycemia/Pages/index.aspx)

Hypoglycemia causes symptoms such as:

- hunger
- shakiness
- nervousness
- sweating
- dizziness or light-headedness
- sleepiness
- confusion
- difficulty speaking
- anxiety
- weakness

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bio.SE. This is a very sensible suggestion, but as [the tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) points out personal medical questions are off-topic. Medical questions that focus on the underlying biology are preferable. As it stands this question should be closed soon because it channels answers into a diagnosis rather than a mechanistic answer.